# phpMyAdmin keep loading for a structure query

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp

I'm just install xampp 3.2.1 for apache and mysql for my assignment.

However import the sql file and check for the data structure, it keeps loading and no any response. I have tried reinstall xampp but it didn't help. Whats wrong with my phpmyadmin? What can I do to fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Open up your favourite Text Editor. Edit the file named `XAMPP\phpMyAdmin\libraries\Util.class.php`

Go to line number around 1618, you will find:

```
return strftime($date, $timestamp);
```

then replace the whole line of code with the following:

```
if(extension_loaded('gettext')) 
  return strftime($date, $timestamp);
```

Try to view the structure of the table again. If the above can't help, try to replace the line with:

```
if(extension_loaded('gettext')){         
date_default_timezone_set('UTC'); 
return gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s', $timestamp + 28800);}
```